# Where should I ask questions about Cyanogenmod?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which of [these](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) Stack Exchange sites I should prefer for questions on rooting my HTC Explorer and installing Cyanogenmod?

Comment: [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) didn't stick out as a primary candidate?

Comment: What _sort_ of questions about Cyanogenmod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/about) is the place to go for most questions you encounter related to *using* your Android device.

That said, be sure to read [the help](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and search before asking - there's a decent chance [your question is already answered](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).